# Iframe and attaching events through jquery

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do, is to pull files from the server side to the client side by using iframes.

The code below receives a json string with paths to files on the server. If the file exists, the file is downloaded, if it fails it should alert me. The alert functionality doesnt work. That is because I fail to attach the 'load' event. 
The load eventhandler should give me the content of the iframe, but that doesnt happen. why? I receive nothing in the console.
    var file_directory="http://localhost/test/";

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/file.php', function(data) {
    for(index in data) {
      if(data[index]=='.' || data[index]=='..')
            continue;

      console.log(file_directory+data[index]);


            var frame= $('<iframe />');  // Create an iframe element
            $('<iframe />', {
                name: 'frame1',
                id: 'frame1'+index,
                src: file_directory+"d"+data[index]                 
            }).appendTo('body');

            $('body').on('onload',frame,function() {
              console.log(1);
              try {
                // Displays the first 50 chars in the innerHTML of the
                // body of the page that the iframe is showing.
                // EDIT 2012-04-17: for wider support, fallback to contentWindow.document
                var doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
                console.log(doc);
                alert(doc.body.innerHTML.substring(0, 50));
              } catch (e) {
                // This can happen if the src of the iframe is
                // on another domain TypeError:Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
                alert('exception: ' + e);
              }
            });
    }

});
```

Comment: $('body').on('onload',frame,function() {  <-- that seems weird.  looks like your trying to do a delegate bind.  In which case it would be 'load' not 'onload' and you can't use delegate binding for that.  load event does not bubble.  you need to bind on the iframe itself.

Comment: `frame` does not appear to be appended to document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The load eventhandler should give me the content of the iframe, but
>   that doesnt happen. why?

`frame` variable is not appended to `document` , `"onload"` is not a jQuery event

`$('body').on('onload',frame,function() {`

is not called for

```
$('<iframe />', {
                name: 'frame1',
                id: 'frame1'+index,
                src: file_directory+"d"+data[index]                 
            }).appendTo('body');
```

`load` event.

---

Try adjusting `js` to

```
var frame = $("<iframe />", {
    name: "frame1",
    id: "frame1" + index,
    src: file_directory + "d" + data[index]
})
// attach `load` event to `frame` before appending `frame` to `body`
.on("load", function() {
    // do stuff
    console.log(1);
    try {
        // Displays the first 50 chars in the innerHTML of the
        // body of the page that the iframe is showing.
        // EDIT 2012-04-17: for wider support, fallback to contentWindow.document
        var doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
        console.log(doc);
        alert(doc.body.innerHTML.substring(0, 50));
    } catch (e) {
        // This can happen if the src of the iframe is
        // on another domain TypeError:Cannot read property "document" of undefined
        alert("exception: " + e);
    }
})
// append `frame` to `body` after attaching `.on("load")` to `frame`
.appendTo("body")
```

Comment: @XWorm _"Cannot read property document of 'undefined'."_ Is `alert`  at `try..catch` ?  Does `js` at post return expected results described at Question _"The alert functionality doesnt work."_ ?

Comment: Actually, now it works fine. When the file exists, it downloads it and when it doesnt it triggers the exception error. Thank you for the answer it worked!!!

Comment: but say, why i dont see the console messages in the try close?

Comment: @XWorm _"why i dont see the console messages in the try close"_ When no exception ?